# SQL PHP get full row with MAX i a single table

Tags: php, sql, max

i have one table collecting scores and other informations like the date and the user id. I would like to get the MAX of the current month and the other fields of the row. I'm having a problem to get the other informations since with functions we cannot get other fields.

I think i should do an inner join but i don't how to make it.

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague.  But if you want one row, then the idea for the solution is `order by` and `fetch first row only`.

In standard SQL, the query would look like:

```
select t.*
from t
where extract(year from datecol) = extract(year from current_date) and
      extract(month from datecol) = extract(month from current_date)
order by t.score desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Databases often differ on database functions.  For instance, many use `year()` and `month()` functions, rather than `extract()`.  Similarly, many databases do not support `fetch first 1 row only`, using `limit` or `select top` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, yes it does work doing this way but the idea was to use MAX (for learning purpose).

Answer (score 0):

I have scores table, with the following fields: id, score, date, user_id

I would like, using MAX, to get the best and latest score of the current month along with the other fields (ie the id, date and user_id).